# Implementation of a new Game of Life Rule

Tags: mathematical-optimization, boolean-computation, cellular-automata

I need to implement a new "game of life" in Mathematica: I have three states — black, red and white. Black means go forward, red go back and white take no action.

I would like to implement the outcomes in this Excel file: http://cl.ly/0s2B2M3h3M2N

The code I have used is the following:

```
input13 = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 
    2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 0, 1, 1}};

getNbhd[A_, i_Integer?Positive, j_Integer?Positive] :=    A[[i - 1 ;; i + 1, j - 1 ;; j + 1]];

evaluateCell[A_, i_, j_] :=   Module[{nbhd, cell = A[[i, j]], numNeighbors},

  If[i == 1 || j == 1 || i == Length[A] || j == Length[A[[1]]],     Return[0]];

  nbhd = getNbhd[A, i, j];   numNeighbors = Apply[Plus, Flatten[nbhd]];

  If[cell == 2 && numNeighbors - 2 >= 4 || 
    numNeighbors - 2 == 3 && numNeighbors - 1 <= 3 || 
    numNeighbors - 2 == 2 && numNeighbors - 1 <= 2 || 
    numNeighbors - 2 == 1 && numNeighbors - 1 <= 1 || 
    numNeighbors - 2 == 0 && numNeighbors - 0 == 8, Return[2];     If[cell == 2 && numNeighbors - 2 == numNeighbors - 1, Return[0], 
    Return[1]]];

  If[cell == 1 && numNeighbors - 1 >= 4 || 
    numNeighbors - 1 == 3 && numNeighbors - 2 <= 3 || 
    numNeighbors - 1 == 2 && numNeighbors - 2 <= 2 || 
    numNeighbors - 1 == 1 && numNeighbors - 2 <= 1 || 
    numNeighbors - 1 == 0 && numNeighbors - 0 == 8, Return[1];     If[cell == 1 && numNeighbors - 1 == numNeighbors - 2, Return[0], 
    Return[2]]];

  If[cell == 0 && numNeighbors - 1 == numNeighbors - 2, Return[0];     If[cell == 0 && numNeighbors - 1 > numNeighbors - 2, Return[1], 
    Return[2]]];]

evaluateAll[A_] :=      
    Table[evaluateCell[A, i, j], {i, 1, Length[A]}, {j, 1, Length[A[[1]]]}];
makeFrames[A_, n_] :=    Map[ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> True] &,   
    NestList[evaluateAll, A, n]]; animate[frames_] := ListAnimate[frames, 1,    
        ControlPlacement -> Top];
```

But running this code I don't have anything special (the colors should be black, grey and white, but after 2 steps I have a red cell, that maybe means that no rule is set for that cell with those neighbors).

Can you help me?

My purpose is also to show that the rule I have made is fractal.

---

I have tried to delete the IFs from the brackets, and now I don't have any red cells, but after 2 step the figures don't change (always the same cell in the same place, they don't interact). Where is the problem??

```
If[ cell == 2 && numNeighbors - 2 >= 4 || 
    numNeighbors - 2 == 3 && numNeighbors - 1 <= 3 || 
    numNeighbors - 2 == 2 && numNeighbors - 1 <= 2 || 
    numNeighbors - 2 == 1 && numNeighbors - 1 <= 1 || 
    numNeighbors - 2 == 0 && numNeighbors - 0 == 8,   Return[2]]; 

If[ cell == 2 && numNeighbors - 2 == numNeighbors - 1, Return[0], Return[1]];

If[ cell == 1 && numNeighbors - 1 >= 4 || 
    numNeighbors - 1 == 3 && numNeighbors - 2 <= 3 || 
    numNeighbors - 1 == 2 && numNeighbors - 2 <= 2 || 
    numNeighbors - 1 == 1 && numNeighbors - 2 <= 1 || 
    numNeighbors - 1 == 0 && numNeighbors - 0 == 8,    Return[1]];

If[ cell == 1 && numNeighbors - 1 == numNeighbors - 2, Return[0],  Return[2]];

If[ cell == 0 && numNeighbors - 1 == numNeighbors - 2, Return[0]];

If[ cell == 0 && numNeighbors - 1 > numNeighbors - 2, Return[1],   Return[2]]];
```

@amr: I had a look to the documentation, but there are only rule already done, I want to have my rule (the one that you can see in the excel file).

Few questions:
1)Should the center cell to be count in the number of neighbors?
2)Is there another way to specify a new rule?
3)Is there a way to discover if the rule that I have created is already implemented in Mathematica with an internal code?
4)May I use a BooleanFunction to do it faster?

Many Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Could you please edit your question to explain what you have tried, and how the spreadsheet outcomes linked in your question relate to the problem.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail your cellular automaton? I don't understand it (yes, I looked at your Excel file, but didn't understand it either). And what do you mean with "making it fractal"?

Comment: Daniele, if you register an account it will be easier for you to edit and update your own questions.  To edit this question you will also need to link the account with your math.stackexchange.com one.

Comment: If I see it correctly, there are `If`s inside other `If`s after `Return` (those which at the current formatting are not in the beginning of a line). Those `If`s will never be executed because of the preceding `Return`. I guess that's the source of your problem. Probably you wanted them to be outside the previous `If`.

Comment: @Daniele Take a look at the [CellularAutomaton](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellularAutomaton.html) function and the [Cellular Automata overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CellularAutomata.html) in the help documentation.

Comment: @DanieleRicci Please don't use flags to ask for help — moderators can't do anything about it. I've added a bounty to attract attention. When you get to 75 rep, you'll be able to add one yourself and in future, please use that mechanism to attract attention :)

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I'm not a programmer and I'm trying to implement this rule in Mathematica, it's for my thesis. 
I will use the right mechanism next time to attract attention.

Comment: It's fine, but please make an effort to use the hints provided. The `CellularAutomaton` function allows you to specify custom rules. Perhaps you can read the docs as amr suggested and update it with where you got stuck...

Comment: I suspect all those `If` statements are not expressing correctly what you would like to do. There are a lot of strange condidions like `cell == 1 && numNeighbors - 1 == numNeighbors - 2` which will *always* evaluate to `False`.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, the approach of using `Apply[Plus, Flatten[nbhd]]` is fatal to your algorithm because summing up the cell-values introduces ambiguities. As an example take these rules from your excel file (White (0), Red (1) and Black (2)). This is in the Excel-file at A43:

```
{{2,2,2},{2,2,0},{0,0,0}} -> 2
```

And this is in A179:

```
{{1,1,1},{1,2,1},{1,1,1}} -> 1
```

For these two rules the center is in both cases Black(2). You could now go through your algorithm and calculate the `numNeighbors` which can be reduced to

```
Plus @@ Flatten@{{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
Plus @@ Flatten@{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}

(*
Out[33]= 10

Out[34]= 10
*)
```

In the following `If` statements in your code, you only use `cell` and `numNeighbors` to distinguish the cases. Since these values are equal for both cases but the result is different, no matter what you do your algorithm will never work correctly.

If you look at your Excel-file closer, than you see that you don't need to specify all the different cases. Your algorithm can be reduced to

> If the number of Red cells is equal to the number of Black cells, then the center cell gets White. Otherwise the center gets the color Red, if we have more Red cells and Black if we have more Black cells.

This can be expressed very easily. First, we make a function which really *counts* the number of red and black cells. Note, that we count the center cell too:

```
countRedBlack[a_, i_, j_] := 
 With[{nb = Flatten@a[[i - 1 ;; i + 1, j - 1 ;; j + 1]]}, 
  Count[nb, #] & /@ {1, 2}]
```

The `evaluateCell` function can then be written down exactly as we *said* it above

```
evaluateCell[a_, i_, j_] := Module[{numRed, numBlack},
  {numRed, numBlack} = countRedBlack[a, i, j];
  Which[numRed == numBlack, 0, numRed > numBlack, 1, True, 2]
]
```

That's it. Let's fix your `evaluatedAll` function by padding the input with 0 so that `evaluateCell` can be called for all inner cells

```
evaluateAll[A_] := With[{paddedA = ArrayPad[A, 1]},
  Table[evaluateCell[paddedA, i, j], 
  {i, 2, Length[A] + 1}, {j, 2,Length[A[[1]]] + 1}]
]
```

And the rest is like you had it

```
makeFrames[A_, n_] := 
 Map[ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> True, ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones"] &, 
  NestList[evaluateAll, A, n]]; 
animate[frames_] := ListAnimate[frames, 1, ControlPlacement -> Top];

data = RandomInteger[2, {100, 100}];
animate[makeFrames[data, 20]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Using `CellularAutomaton`

I didn't consider giving the `CellularAutomaton` solution because I had the feeling that the OP wanted to implement the automaton by himself.
Using the included `CellularAutomaton` makes the whole solution a one-liner.

With @Simon Woods idea consisting of `Sign` and `Total` we define a function which makes the transition for one cell. Neighborhood range is 1 in both directions, therefore `{1,1}` and we want to calculate 10 steps of a random array of size 300x300:

```
a=CellularAutomaton[{Sign[Total[Flatten[#]]]&,{},{1,1}},RandomInteger[{-1,1},{300,300}],10];
```

Creating an image sequence from `a` gives

```
ListAnimate[ImageApply[Which[# == 0, {0.94, 0., 0.01}, 
 # == 1, {0.15, 0.11,0.16},True, {0.16, 0.42, 0.12}] &, Image[#]] & /@ a]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice work deducing the rule!

Comment: Good answer. Just wondering, is the CellularAutomaton function capable of this kind of action...?

Comment: @cormullion See my update.

Comment: Do you think that if I want to change color scheme, i can apply the following code?

Comment: I mean to COUNT 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2, and the change rule, can i write the following code?
> countRedBlack[a_, i_Integer?Positive, j_Integer?Positive] := 
 With[{nb = Flatten@a[[i - 1 ;; i + 1, j - 1 ;; j + 1]]}, 
  Count[nb, #] & /@ {0, 1}]

Comment: evaluateCell[a_, i_, j_] := 
 Module[{numWhite, numBlack}, {numWhite, numBlack} = 
   countRedBlack[a, i, j];
  Which[numWhite == numBlack, 2, numWhite > numBlack, 0, 
   numBlack > numWhite, 1]]

Answer (score 7):

Given the rule as explained by Halirutan...

> If the number of Red cells is equal to the number of Black cells, then
>   the center cell gets White. Otherwise the center gets the color Red,
>   if we have more Red cells and Black if we have more Black cells.

...it's interesting to note how things work if we use the following mapping of colours to numbers:

> Red = -1 , White = 0 , Black = +1

The rule can then be expressed as:

> The centre cell gets the value `Sign[total of all cell values in the neighbourhood]`

The evolution step can thus be expressed as a convolution with a 3x3 `BoxMatrix` followed by taking the `Sign`:

```
data = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {300, 300}];
frames = NestList[Sign@ListConvolve[BoxMatrix[1], #, {2, 2}] &, data, 20];
ListAnimate[Image /@ Rescale[frames]]
```

[image]

If you want to colour Red cells red, White cells white and Black cells black, use:

```
ListAnimate[ArrayPlot[#, ColorRules -> {-1 -> Red, 0 -> White, 1 -> Black}] & /@ frames]
```

Comment: Shouldn't something here be red? --poke-- --poke--

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, are you implying that my colouring scheme, in which "Red" is black, "White" is gray, and "Black" is white, is in some way deficient? ;-)